# Are these 9.2 CASE tools instructions still valid using ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, schema-architecture

The [Using CASE tools in ArcGIS 10](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/05/using-case-tools-in-arcgis-10/) document links to some older documentation at [Building geodatabases with case tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/building-geodatabases-case-tools), which specifically mentions ArcGIS 9.2 throughout.

Are these instructions still valid for creating a geodatabase using CASE tools? Is there a more up-to-date set of instructions which I should follow instead?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the recommended route for designing a geodatabase in ArcGIS 10.x is to use the [GeoDatabase Diagrammer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5af1723bab4e413bae63dd89daa87984).

This stand-alone tool allows you to generate the schema then export to XML. This XML can be used to generate a geodatabase in ArcCatalog.

The GDB Diagrammer can also import the XML schema exported from ArcCatalog. This can be used as a starting point for further modifications of the schema.

Comment: The UML to XMI export tool mentioned in those instructions was dropped by Microsoft after Visio 2003 also and is no longer supported by Microsoft. So those old instructions are unlikely to work anymore.